# How to use weak learners in Adaboost?

Tags: machine-learning, adaboost, ensemble-learning

I'm using Adaboost and here is a question about weak learners. In the Adaboost algorithm, as follows, in step (2), can I use different algorithms? For example, when k is 1, I use KNN, if k=2, SVM is used and for k=3, I use decision tree? Or, should I use a single algorithm in all k iteration of the **for** loop?

```
(1) initialize the weight of each tuple in D to 1=d;
(2) for i = 1 to k do // for each round:
(3) sample D with replacement according to the tuple weights to obtain Di ;
(4) use training set Di to derive a model, Mi ;
(5) compute error.Mi/, the error rate of Mi (Eq. 8.34)
(6) if error.Mi/ > 0.5 then
(7) go back to step 3 and try again;
(8) endif
(9) for each tuple in Di that was correctly classified do
(10) multiply the weight of the tuple by error.Mi/=.1error.Mi//; // update    weights
(11) normalize the weight of each tuple;
(12) endfor
```

Answer (score 2):

Adaboost is usually used with week learners, like short decision trees. You can use more complicated learners but in that case Adaboost might not be the best choice to combine results.

Most implementations (like the Scikit learn [AdaBoostClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html)) assume that you will be using the same learner for each step, but it shouldn't be too difficult to change this.

Also, this question might be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks. But another question is that for a weak learner like KNN, a  training sample is given a specific label in every iteration. What is the advantage of Adaboost in this case?

Comment: @Pegah Adaboost will increase the weight of misclassified examples at each iteration. So if you use KNN at `i=1` and SVN at `i=2` (where `i` is the iteration of Adaboost), the SVM algorithm will try harder to correctly classify examples that were misclassified by KNN. Using KNN at multiple iterations wouldn't help because KNN is an unsupervised algorithm and would return the same result each time (unless you fit the data to find the best k).

Comment: Perhaps someone can relate to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936175/custom-learner-function-for-adaboost